# Show every $a \in E^*$ is a root of $x^{p^d-1} -1 $?

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

Let $\mathbb{Z}_p < E$ be an extension field of degree $d$. A simple counting argument shows:

$|E^*| = p^d - 1$

Proposition: For all $\alpha \in  E^*$, $x^{p^d-1} -1 = 0.$

In a field of $p^d -1 $ elements, does that number equal 0 automatically in a field?

If it does, than $\alpha^0 = 1$ which means 1 - 1 = 0, which means it is a root. If my logic correct?

EDIT:

Okay, so we want to show that every $\alpha \in E^*$ is a zero in $x^{p^d-1} -1$ or $x^{p^d-1} -1 = 0$

How about this:

By Fermat $a^{p-1} \equiv 1\mod p$              (I don't know how to type congruent)

$x^{p^d-1} \equiv 1 \mod p$

Where is my understanding lacking so I can deduce from this that any element is 0?

Comment: What do you mean with ‘any element is zero’?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E^*$ denotes the set of no-zero elements in the field $E$. As $E$ has $p^d$ elements, $E^*$ has $p^d-1$.

Your proposition is false: a power of a non-zero element in a field can't be $0$ since it has an inverse. Are you sure the correct assertion is not $\,x^{p^d-1}=1$, or $\,x^{p^d-1}-1=0\,$?

*Edit:* This is a sort of generalisation of Fermat, which says that for every element in $\mathbf F_p=\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z$ satisfies the equation $x^p-x=0$.

Thus, in the field $\mathbf F_{p^2}$, which is the splitting field of any irreducible quadratic polynomial, all elements will satisfy the equation $x^{p^2}-x=0$, and all non-zero elements will satisfy $x^{p^2-1}-1=0$, i. e. they will all be roots of unity.

Comment: yes it indeed is. I made an error. My apologies.

Comment: Alright, so we are raising an element of our extension field by the number of all non zero elements. Why is that significant? Cant you give me a hint in the right direction?

Comment: It's a generalisation of Little Fermat. With this, you deduce these non-zero elements satisfy the equation $x^{p^d}-x=0$, which is also satisfied by $x=0$ (hence by all elements in $E$). From there, you can show there is, up to isomorphism, only one field with $p^d$  elementsn and that the field with $p^d$ elements is contained in the field with $p^e$ elements if and only if $d\mid e$.

Comment: Is there anyway you can give me a concrete example so I can understand? With like a real function or something? I see a similarity to fermat, but that's only in the exponents of the sides. Am I allowed to just equare the exponents with Fermat? Does this definition have some type of name where I can read more about it?

Comment: @user121615: I added some details/ examples. Is it clearer?

Comment: Yes. Thanks! I think I got what I need.